# Electron + NodeJs + React + Zustand: Viewing large files

Tags: reactjs, node.js, electron, frontend, zustand

I just want to know if I am doing this wrong.

I my server performs calculations and streams text result to my frontend. I have many calculations running at the same time, so I store the results inside my Zustand store. This is causing the app to freeze.

At the same time the streams are also written to the file system. The end results is around 800KB to 1.4MB text files with around 30,000 lines.

Is Zustand the problem? Or is it React? What are the alternatives?